How to Maintain Texture Dimensions in Three.js When Scaling Mesh?
I am working on a Three.js project where I have a mesh object with a texture applied. The texture is a PNG file with dimensions 64x64.
Problem:
When the dimensions of the mesh object change, the texture gets stretched in height and width, which distorts its appearance. I want the texture to maintain its original dimensions (64x64) regardless of the mesh's size.
When the mesh is 64x64

When the mesh is 16x07 (or anything other than NxN)

I have tried looking into texture properties and material settings in Three.js but couldn't find a way to keep the texture dimensions fixed while scaling the mesh.
How can I prevent the texture from stretching and keep it at its original 64x64 size when the mesh dimensions change in Three.js?
Here is how the meshObject & material is created
Material Creation
function _createMaterial(url: string): THREE.MeshBasicMaterial {
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    this.loader.load(url, (texture) => {
        texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
        material.setValues({ map: texture });
    });
    return material;
}

MeshObject Creation
this._meshObject = new Utils3.myTHREE.Mesh(geometry, material);


The solution provided by Łukasz D. Mastalerz also makes sense, but for my use case, I eliminated the texture approach and used sprites.
Sprite creation:
    private static _createSprite(url: string): THREE.Sprite {
        let spriteMaterial: THREE.SpriteMaterial = null;
        let sprite: THREE.Sprite = new THREE.Sprite(); // Initialize the sprite
    
        this.loader.load(url, (texture) => {
            // Create a sprite material with the loaded texture
            spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: texture });
        
            // Assign the material to the sprite
            sprite.material = spriteMaterial;
    
            // Set the dimensions of the sprite
            sprite.scale.set(32, 32, 1);
    
            // Indicate that the sprite needs an update
            sprite.material.needsUpdate = true;
    
            // this.render(); // Uncomment if you need to render the scene after loading the texture
        });
    
        // Return the sprite, even if the texture is not done loading
        return sprite;
    }

The line,
// Set the dimensions of the sprite  
sprite.scale.set(32, 32, 1);

plays the important role of fitting the image inside the mesh object.
Here is the final result


Of course always ending solution up to you. But keep in mind that Sprite is always faces towards the camera . That can be crucial in 3D environment. Simple, switch Decal on Sprite in my Pen, then you will see what I am talking about. If that solution is still good for you… that’s good. ;)

You can try using: non-indexed geometry and divide the mesh manually, you can use a custom shader and create a mapped shader on the geometry, you can try to manually modify the UV on the mapped geometry, you can try to use several materials (custom shader) on geometry. But all these efforts will be pointless because if you don't isolate the texture from the geometry, it will always depend on it.

Note: After the initial use of a texture, its dimensions, format, and
type cannot be changed...

Always will be stretched, repeated, etc., basically that makes sense in mapping, right?
If I were you, I would use DecalGeometry in this particular case. This allows the two geometries to be manipulated independently. Moreover, from the pictures you showed, this is what it looks like to me, let's say, as a decal.
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2);
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture = loader.load('https://media.craiyon.com/2023-11-26/2ets6-v1SVGOdKAtPxmlMw.webp');
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, wireframe: true });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

const position = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
const orientation = new THREE.Euler();
const size = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1 ,1);

const decalGeometry = new DecalGeometry(mesh, position, orientation, size);
const decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: -1 });
const decalMesh = new THREE.Mesh(decalGeometry, decalMaterial);

https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/full/VwOrYGR
UPDATE
Sprite - version where texture is always faced towards the camera. Important in 3d context.
https://codepen.io/Lucas_Mas/full/wvbPrvW

I also arrived at the same solution, but due to some specific requirements in my use case, I went with another approach of using sprites. Nonetheless, thanks for your input.
